# loop in discord.js Slash command builders Choices

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make dynamic slash command option choices based on my database

this is what I trying to do

```
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('delpay')
.setDescription('Remove Payment Option')
.addStringOption(option =>
    option.setName('code')
        .setDescription('Input Payment Code [Case Sensitive]')
        .setRequired(true)
        //example what I try to do//
        for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
            .addChoice(payment[i])
            }
)
}
```

But i cant do the for loop in there!. Can you explain where i wrong? And can you explain other method i can use for that case and the example for that? Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE

I find the workaround. There is nothing wrong with the for loop placement but there is some changes I need to do

```
module.exports = {
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('delpay')
.setDescription('Remove Payment Option')
.addStringOption(option =>{
    
    option.setName('code')
        .setDescription('Input Payment Code [Case Sensitive]')
        .setRequired(true)
        
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ){
            option.addChoice(list[i].name,list[i].code)
        }
        return option
    
    }
            
)

 }
```

Now the code working. Thankyou for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `option.addChoice`, otherwise it will have a SyntaxError

```js
for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
    option.addChoice(payment[i])
}
```

Comment: hmmm i don't know if this related or not but the problem is not about how i do the loop but where i declare the loop. I'm using vscode for writing my code and they automatically detect there is and error because they read the for() not as looping syntax but ass function